# Look up values within a cell in R

Tags: r

I would like to look up values for individual ids separated by commas in each cell of a column.

The data (df) look like this:

```
  products
1 1,3,5
2 1,2
3 3
4 NA
5 4,5
```

I would like to look up the values for each number from a different df (df1) and get the result as follows:

```
  products
1 apple, carrot, pear
2 apple, peach
3 carrot
4 NA
5 tomato, pear
```

Is there any easy way of doing this in R?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a lookup dataframe like the following :

```
df1 <- data.frame(products = 1:5, 
           value = c('apple', 'peach', 'carrot', 'tomato', 'pear'))
```

We can bring the comma-separated value into separate rows and then join with `df1` by `products` and summarise the `value` into one comma-separated string with `toString`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(products, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'products') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(value = toString(value)) %>%
  select(-row)


# A tibble: 5 x 1
#  value              
#  <chr>              
#1 apple, carrot, pear
#2 apple, peach       
#3 carrot             
#4 NA                 
#5 tomato, pear
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(products = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 4L), .Label = c("1,2", 
"1,3,5", "3", "4,5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=read.table(text="
products
1 1,3,5
2 1,2
3 3
4 NA
5 4,5",h=T)

df1=data.frame(id=1:5,name=c("apple","peach","carrot","tomato","pear"))

data.frame(products=
  apply(df,1,function(x){
    paste0(df1$name[match(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),","))),df1$id)],collapse=", ")
  })
)
             products
1 apple, carrot, pear
2        apple, peach
3              carrot
4                  NA
5        tomato, pear
```